# Replace some HTML tags with special characters with Python

Tags: python, html, regex, string, replace

I have some strings that contain some HTML tags like `<strong>`, `<em>` and `<br/>` and I need to substitute these tags with `*`, `_` and `\n` respectively;

**for example:**

`"this string contain <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em> formatted text.<br/>How can I substitute these <strong><em>HTML tags</em></strong> with <strong>Python</strong>?"`

**must become**

`"this string contain *bold* and _italic_ formatted text.\nHow can I substitute these *_HTML tags_* with *Python*?"`.

Whats the best pratices to do this? Maybe regular expressions? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Whats the best pratices to do this? Maybe regular expressions?*

Definitely not, regular expressions are good fit for dealing with Chomsky Type-3, when you need to work with Chomsky Type-2.

You might use [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) built-in module following way

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
changes = {"strong": "*", "em": "_", "br": "\n"}
class Converter(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.out = ""
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.out += changes.get(tag, tag)
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag != "br":
            self.out += changes.get(tag, tag)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.out += data

txt = "this string contain <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em> formatted text.<br/>How can I substitute these <strong><em>HTML tags</em></strong> with <strong>Python</strong>?"

conv = Converter()
conv.feed(txt)
print(conv.out)
```

output

```
this string contain *bold* and _italic_ formatted text.
How can I substitute these *_HTML tags_* with *Python*?
```

Note that I ignore `br` endtag as otherwise `<br/>` would result in double newline.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know html.parser module. I also had to import abc and include ABC as a base class of Converter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't *speak* python, but replace `</?strong>` with `*` and `</?em>` with `_` should do it.

`</?strong>` matches `<strong>` *and* `</strong>` since the `/` is made optional by the `?`.

[Example for strong here on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/wsh2hD/1)

Comment: Thank you, this solution works but I think that @Daweo solution is more "Pythonic".